# getting NULL cache

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am working with NSCache in iOS i have following code in .h file for cache:

```
    NSCache *_cache;
```

I am adding the image which are downloading  from the url to the cache in .m:

```
-(void)cacheFromURL:(NSURL*)url
```

{
    [_cache setCountLimit:50];

```
UIImage* newImage = [_cache objectForKey:url.description];
if( !newImage )
{


    NSError *err = nil;

    if(url!=Nil)
    {
        newImage=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&err]];
    }
    if( newImage )
    {

        [_cache setValue:newImage forKey:url.description];

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog( @"UIImageView:LoadImage Failed: %@", err );
    }

    if(_cache==Nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"nil");  
    }

    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"cache is not nil");
    }
}
```

}

But i am getting the nil cache every time . where i can see the downloading process in log . 
why am i getting null cache?

Comment: Where do you create your cache object?

Comment: i am getting exception if i am initialize :setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ffdds'

Comment: You need to create/initialize the [`NSCache`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object before you can add and object to it. Also you need to add object with the [`setObject:forKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008976-CH1-SW7)

Comment: @rckoenes:you are right.it was my bad. It is working with setObject.you can post this in answer so i can accept and up vote your  answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create/initialize the [`NSCache`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object before you can add and object to it. Also you need to add object with the [`setObject:forKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008976-CH1-SW7)

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your `NSCache` object first:

```
_cache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
```

Comment: i am getting exception if i am initialize :setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ffdds'